# What is the color of viral particles?

Tags: visible-light

I [read today on twitter](https://twitter.com/Emmanigma/status/1241439731830882304?s=20) that because COVID-19 particle is very small (<100nm) and visible light wavelength is larger (>250nm) the virus has no "colour".

I know that some [molecular bonds vibrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_vibration) at deep IR frequencies, and [some amino acids are fluorescent](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-46312-4_16)

But if we have a crystal of or a droplet with viral particles, will there be visible color? What defines that color?

Comment: Crystal of lipid droplets?

Comment: @CosmasZachos i guess, either. Or a cuvette with X moles of virus

Comment: Interactions with solvent will inevitably cause collision broadening of discrete lines into broad bands.  As for crystallization, good luck.  It's hard enough to crystallize a pure protein, and virus particles' coats comprise dozens of protein molecules.  If (big if) you succeed, there will be interstitial pockets of solvent.